# Problems rounding datetime to nearest hour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a 4 dataframes with the objective of merging them around the date column, by hour, to make inferences based on interactions with tweets.

In order for the dataframe to be properly manicured, I need to round the date column to the nearest hour, and then merge dataframes around the hour, as mentioned.

My problem has been with rounding the datetime objects to the nearest hour. Below is my code, and I cannot figure out how to get it to round correctly.

```
import datetime
tweet_and_price_df['date'] = tweet_and_price_df['date'].apply(lambda dt: 
    datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, 
    round(dt.hour),round(dt.minute)))
```

The output is correctly rounding the minute, but not to the hour. Here is a snippet from the output:

[image: Screenshot of output]

If anyone has any ideas why it's not rounding the hour up/down, please let me know!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
tweet_and_price_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(tweet_and_price_df['date']).round('H')
```

Comment: This does work with the dataframe, thank you! But since these are sensitive towards the nearest hour, i need to round to the closest hour.

Comment: @Falcon change floor to round ~